# Access object properties from prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have a class that wraps a mongodb client for node.js.  The the class below when I call `findUsers` I get that `this.collection` is undefined.

How do I access `this.collection` from the prototype?

Thank you!

Class:

```
var Users;

Users = (function () {

    function Users(db) {

        db.collection('users', function (err, collection) {
           this.collection = collection;
        });
    }

    Users.prototype.findUsers = function (callback) {

        this.collection.find({}, function (err, results) {

        });
    }

    return Users;

})();
```

Usage:

```
//db holds the db object already created
var user = new Users(db);
user.findUsers();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it right in the prototype method, your error is in the callback function of `db.collection()`.

```
var Users = (function () {
    function Users(db) {
        var that = this; // create a reference to "this" object
        db.collection('users', function (err, collection) {
            that.collection = collection; // and use that
        });
    }
    Users.prototype.findUsers = function (callback) {
        this.collection.find({}, function (err, results) {

        });
    }
    return Users;
})();
```

Comment: in fact, that did the job. :D

Answer (score -1):

Use another reference:

```
Users = (function(){
    var that = this;

    function users(db)
    {
         db.collection('users', function(err, collection)
         {
              that.collection = collection;
         }
    }
})();
```

Comment: `that` refers to the global object in your solution.

Comment: It seems this has conflicts with other objects.  I have two classes very similar to this, but when I do a `console.log` on `this.collection` from findUsers it returns the collection from the other class.